# Windows 10 BackgroundUploader breaks after app restart

Tags: windows-10-universal

I'm trying to upload some video files using [BackgroundUploader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207140) component.
It works great if I keep the application open until the transfer completes.
It also works great if the app is closed, the transfer is completed under the hood, which is great.

But it doesn't work if the application is restarted (rerun normally) before the transfer is finished. Simply put, there is no sign of error, the [UploadOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.uploadoperation) status is running but nothing happens anymore regarding this upload request.

I can see using [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org) that the transfer is stopped:

[image: WireShark screenshot]

When the application starts there is no code that does anything regarding [BackgroundUploader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207140).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but it behaves as normal when the app is not run from Visual Studio even if it is only **Start Without Debugging**.

Is this some kind of know issue or limitation?
What will happen with background transfers if the app is updated via **Windows Store** in the middile?